# GdxRuntimeException: #iterator() cannot be used nested

Tags: java, libgdx, iteration

I'm working on this game which has a `World`. In this `World` there are many `Units`.

The problem stems from the fact that `World` serves (among other things) two main tasks:

1. Iterate through each `Unit` so that they can update their properties based on time passed an so forth.
2. Find potential targets for each `Unit`.

In `World`, this happens:

```
for (Actor a : stage.getActors())
{
    a.draw(batch, 1);
    a.act(10);
    findTargets((Unit)a);
}
```

findTargets() is defined as such:

```
public ArrayList<Unit> findTargets(Unit source) {
    double sight = source.SIGHT;
    ArrayList<Unit> targets = new ArrayList<Unit>();
    for (Actor a : stage.getActors()) {
        Unit target = (Unit)a;
        if (!(target instanceof Unit))
            continue;

        if (target.equals(source)) continue;
        if (((Unit)target).getPos().dst(source.getPos()) < sight) {
            targets.add((Unit)target);
        }
    }
    return targets;
}
```

The problem is obvious: `findTargets()` also iterates over every unit, resulting in a nested iteration. However, I'm unsure as to how I should proceed to "un-nest" this, as I'm only seeing a catch 22: Every unit does in effect have to iterate over every other unit to see if they're within their sight-range.

Some fresh eyes on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use a traditional for loop instead of an iterator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There may be ways to refactor your design to avoid the nesting. But the simplest solution might be to just use the old school for loops for both outer and inner, or just the inner. Don't use the iterator, as that is not allowed here for nested loops. getActors returns a libGDX Array, so just traverse that by index

```
for (int i=0; i < stage.getActors().size; i++) {
  //...etc --> use stage.getActors().items[i] ...
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I decided to try, then less than 30 seconds after I did, I saw your sollution. Worked like a charm, thanks.